# vba qdf.OpenRecordset parameter

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters

The following VBA runs but i have to enter the season (2016) in a pop up window 
how do i get this to execute without having to enter the season manually?

```
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set DB = CurrentDb

Dim season As String
season = 2016

Set qdf = DB.QueryDefs("qryrptInvoiceAamxAFeb2")
qdf.Parameters("Enter season 2016 or 2017") = season
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: show query definition source sql

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the query parameter in `[]` square brackets both in code and the query itself.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qryrptInvoiceAamxAFeb2")
    .Parameters("[Enter season 2016 or 2017]").Value = season
    Set rs = .OpenRecordset()
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Open the query `qryrptInvoiceAamxAFeb2` in design mode. you should see the question "Enter season 2016 or 2017" in there - remove it and replace it with 2016. then

```
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set DB = CurrentDb

'Dim season As String
'season = 2016

Set qdf = DB.QueryDefs("qryrptInvoiceAamxAFeb2")
'qdf.Parameters("Enter season 2016 or 2017") = season
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```